# Error al insertar tipo float en Oracle desde c# WPF

Tags: c#, oracle, wpf

Tengo un valor de tipo float en c# y al intentar insertarlo en la bd en un campo de tipo float me salta el error: ORA-00913: too many values'
Recojo el float de un textbox, hago el cambio a float:

```
float.Parse(txt_price.Text.Replace(".",","))
```

Le pongo el replace porque si no no me coge el signo de puntuación y me lo coge como si fuera entero
código de la inserción a la bd:

```
bd.setData("insert into products(idproduct,name,description,price,deleted,stock) values(idproduct.nextval,'"+this.Name+"','"+this.Description+"',"+this.price+","+this.deleted+","+this.stock+")");
```

donde la variable float es this.stock

Comment: Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: Por favor se más claro en la pregunta, y agrega más código para analizar, si el INSERT produce el problema muéstranos toda esa parte del código, ya que tu error es sobre los parámetros que estás ingresando, no sobre la conversión del dato.

Comment: actualizado con esa informacion